Can you have a Kotlin property with an abstract setter but an implemented getter?
I'd like to have a property with an abstract setter and an implemented getter. However, I can't make anything along these lines compile:
abstract class MyType {
    abstract val complexObject: ComplexObject
    
    abstract var myProperty: String
        get() = complexObject.someDerivationLogic
}

Something like this will compile:
abstract class MyType {
    abstract val complexObject: ComplexObject
    
    fun getMyProperty(): String {
        return complexObject.someDerivationLogic
    }
    
    abstract fun setMyProperty(newValue: String)
}

But then the myType.myProperty syntax no longer works.
I can actually solve this by dropping to Java:
public interface MyType {
    String getComplexObject();

    default String getMyProperty() {
        return getComplexObject().someDerivationLogic;
    }
    void setMyProperty(String foo);
}

And then I can implement in Kotlin and use the both getters and setters from Kotlin with myType.myProperty.
Is there a way to do this without including some Java? Or is there a more Kotlin-y way to achieve this?

FWIW: I think the most obvious Kotlin way would be to add abstract set after the getter — but that gives the errors property with getter implementation cannot be abstract and modifier 'abstract' is not applicable to 'setter'.
